# $_post in Kohana controller

Tags: forms, post, view, controller, kohana

i was wondering if i can get a variable with $_post, in a kohana controller if the controller doesn't 'control' a form.

So, if i insert in a view something like:

```
 <form name="ordering" id="ordering" method="post" action="">
 <input type="hidden" id="ordering" value="0">  
 <select id="ordering" name="ordering">   
....
```

in the controller i put :

```
        $ordering = $_POST['ordering'];
```

but gives me an error

or

```
       if ($this->request->method == 'POST') {    
        $ordering = $_POST['ordering'];
    }
```

but in this case it never gets there(at this bunch of code).

so my question is: how can i retrieve in a controller a $_post variable if the controller doesn't handle only a form? thank you!

Comment: I'm sure you can get what you want without doing it in wrong way. =]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kohana 3.0 :

```
if ($_POST)
{
$ordering = arr::get($_POST, 'ordering');
...
```

Kohana 3.1 :

```
if ($ordering = $this->request->post('ordering')) // or just $this->request->post()
{
...
```

Comment: i use kohana 3.0. i tried the code, but then if i try to use back the $ordering variable in the view, it doesn't work.(i get an undefined variable error)...

Comment: @dana have you got an submit button or sth like that? otherwise $ordering does not exist

Comment: @dana if you don't intend to set variable even before checking for post, use bind() when setting View vars (instead of set())

Answer (score 1):

PHP will issue a notice if you attempt to access an undefined array element.
So if the "ordering" form was never submitted, attempting to access $_POST['ordering'] will result in

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: ordering in ...
```

Kohana's Arr class provides a nice helper method to get around this.

If you call

```
$ordering = Arr::get($_POST, 'ordering', 0);
```

It will retrieve the ordering value from the post variable. If $_POST['ordering'] is not set, it will return the third parameter instead. You can then try `if ($ordering) ...`

This is useful for $_POST/$_GET arrays, or any function that accepts arrays – it allows you to concisely specify a fallback behavior rather than having to test with `isset`.

One of the advantages of Kohana is that the source code tends to be very clean and easy to understand (which is nice because documentation is sparse.) I'd suggest you take a check out the Kohana_Arr class and look at the methods available!

Answer (score 1):

ID's are unique! Use class insted or different IDs.

Your form and the select both have got ordering, change one to something else, like:

```
<form name="ordering_form" id="ordering_form" method="post" action="">
<input type="hidden" id="ordering_input" value="0">  
<select id="ordering" name="ordering">
...
</select>
</form>
```

and in your Kohana Controller:

```
if( isset( $_POST['ordering'] ) )
{
    $ordering = $_POST['ordering'];
}
```

this should work, because i cant find any other error

Comment: HTML element IDs have nothing to do with $_POST, names do. In this case value of the last element with name="ordering" will be submitted, although being duplicate.